# Undefined control sequence if I add % before gdef

Tags: beamer

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
%
{\gdef\x{Hello}}%
%
\x

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This code does not compile. xelatex 2023 gives error

> Undefined control sequence. \end{frame}

But if I remove the percent signs, the code compiles.

I thought comments are non-essential. Why does it matter here?

Comment: That's because you've put the `\gdef` in the frame's title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\begin{frame}[t]
%
{\gdef\x{Hello}}%
%
\x
```

is equivalent to

```
\begin{frame}[t]{\gdef\x{Hello}}\x
```

which is starts a frame with option `t`, sets the frame's title to `\frametitle{\gdef\x{Hello}}` and puts `\x` in the body.

If you modify it to

```
  %
  {\gdef\x{Hello}\x}%
  %
```

you will get a frame with no body but the title 'Hello'. But this definition is not effective in the body of the frame. The same effect can be seen without the comment sign.

```
\begin{frame}[t]
  {\gdef\x{Hello}}%
  %
  \x
```

will also give the same error because `\x` is defined in the title rather than the body.

To avoid this, leave a blank line, remove the (here pointless) braces around `\gdef`, provide empty arguments for the frame title and subtitle

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[t]{}{}
  {\gdef\x{Hello}}%
  %
  \x
  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

or stop TeX searching for arguments

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[t]\relax
  {\gdef\x{Hello}}%
  %
  \x
  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

or otherwise make clear the definition is not the frame's title.

Comment: Oh oh, I'm blind. I forgot it is the place for title!

Comment: @Gqqnbig If you used `\frametitle{}` you might not even have known. But it is easy not to see these things once you've convinced yourself the difference is some other thing.

Comment: I dream of a time when “optional braced arguments” are declared abominable and banned from the face of earth. 

Comment: @egreg I think they're especially bad in cases like this: `frame` doesn't even limit itself to *one*. Even `\begin{frame}{title}{\gdef\x...}\x` produces an error. But I suppose it was hard to find alternative delimiters in this particular case.